# Android ListView not showing content

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I am following [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/56109/make-first-android-app-part-2) tutorial for Android development:

I am on the ListView section of the tutorial. So far, my app has a text field where the user enter a name. They then press the button and their name should be saved and appear in a ListView in the bottom half of the screen. I using the exact same code as the tutorial but my problem is that the ListView does not show anything after I press the button. The following is some of my java and xml code:

//MainActivity.java

```
    package com.theboss.jackli.omgandroid;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View
        .OnClickListener
{
    TextView mainTextView;
    Button mainButton;
    EditText mainEditText;
    ListView mainListView;
    ArrayAdapter mArrayAdapter;
    ArrayList mNameList = new ArrayList();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // 1. Access the TextView defined in layout XML
        // and then set its text
        mainTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.main_textview);
        mainTextView.setText("Set in Java!");

        // 2. Access the Button defined in layout XML
        // and listen to it here
        mainButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_button);
        mainButton.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) this);

        // 3. Access the EditText defined in layout XML
        mainEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.main_edittext);

        // todo ListView content not showing.
        // 4. Access the ListView
        mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_listview);

        // Create an ArrayAdapter for the ListView
        mArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mNameList);

        // Set the ListView to use the ArrayAdapter
        mainListView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);

        // Also add that value to the list shown in the ListView
        mNameList.add(mainEditText.getText().toString());
        mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // Test output to logs
        for (int i = 0; i < mNameList.size(); i++)
        {
            String contents = mNameList.get(i).toString();
            Log.d("OMG Android mNameList: ", contents);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // Take what was typed into the EditText and use in TextView
        mainTextView.setText(mainEditText.getText().toString()
                + " is yoloing on Android development!");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is the xml code:

```
<!-- activity_main.xml -->

   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/textview"/>

    <!-- This nested layout contains views of its own -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <!-- Set OnClickListener to trigger results when pressed -->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/main_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="@string/button" />
        <!-- Shows an image from your drawable resources -->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        <!-- Closing tag for the horizontal nested layout -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Displays keyboard when touched -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/main_edittext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:hint="@string/hint" />

    <!-- List whose dataset is defined in code with an adapter -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/main_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I googled and tried various things for about two hours but can't find the issue. The minimum supported version I selected is 4.0.3. I tried removing the "layout_weight" from the ListView and giving a "layout_height" of 20dp just to see if it was a rendering issue but nothing appears still. Whether or not I use an actual layout_height or layout_weight, there is a bar that is highlighted that appears to be where the ListView is if I click it. The problem is that no content is ever displayed there. Seems to be some issue with the text field value being saved or transferred to the ListView. Any insight on this would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Where's your listview and how are you inflating it?

Comment: It's defined in the xml file below the java. Sorry if it is confusing. I'll try to separate the sections in my question for the two pieces of code.

Comment: You are not adding your textViews to ArrayList, add textViews to arrayList and set adapter after doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `mNameList` is initially empty. in onClick you should add the new item to the `ArrayAdapter`'s dataset. Change your onClick like:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // Take what was typed into the EditText and use in TextView
        mainTextView.setText(mainEditText.getText().toString()
                + " is yoloing on Android development!");
        mArrayAdapter.add(mainEditText.getText().toString());
    }
```

fill up your `EditText` and click on the button